# Find lower bound for a sequence of integral

Tags: real-analysis

I have a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ only satisfies the conditions: $f\ge 0$, $\int_{ - \infty }^\infty  {f\left( x \right)dx}  > 0$, continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and has compactly supported on $[-M,M]$. My work requires a lower bound for the quantity
$$ \int_{ - \infty }^\infty  {\left| {f\left( x \right)\sin \left( {{a_n}x} \right)} \right|dx} ,$$
where $(a_n)$ is a sequence of $n$ such that $a_n\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$. That means I expect to find an estimate in the form $\int_{ - \infty }^\infty  {\left| {f\left( x \right)\sin \left( {{a_n}x} \right)} \right|dx}  \geqslant \operatorname{const} .{\varepsilon _n}$, where $(\varepsilon_n)$ is a positive sequence for which $\varepsilon_n \to 0$. Can any someone help me this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You have:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)|\sin(a_nx)|dx\geq \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)(\sin(a_nx))^2dx$$
hence
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)|\sin(a_nx)|dx\geq \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)dx -\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)\cos(2a_nx)dx=\frac{I}{2}-\varepsilon_n$$
and
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)\cos(2a_nx)dx=\varepsilon_n\to 0$$ if $n\to +\infty$.

Comment: It's great. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Kelenner: Nice (+1)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given us any condition that prevents $f$ from being $0$ everywhere, so no positive lower bounds are possible.

Comment: I omitted a condition $\int_{ - \infty }^\infty  {f\left( x \right)dx}  > 0$.